# Unity setting Button's onClick in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2020.3 and making basically a question-answer game.

Assume that I have this  two functions:

```
public void TrueAnswer()
{
    Debug.Log("True !");
}

public void FalseAnswer()
{
    Debug.Log("False !");
}
```

In every question, true answer's button is changing(For example, in xth question the answer is in first button but in x+1th question the answer is in third button). So, I should change answer buttons onClick event in every question. Depend on my research, there is some ways like:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

m_YourFirstButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
m_YourSecondButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate {TaskWithParameters("Hello"); });
m_YourThirdButton.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClicked(42));
m_YourThirdButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
```

(This is from Unity Documentation, version 2019.1)

```
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

button.GetComponent<Button>().clicked += ButtonClicked;
```

(This is what I understand from Unity Documentation version 2020.3 and what VS 2019 IntelliSense recommend me to use "clicked" event. 2020.3 also has onClicked event but it is obsolote)

First, I used the first way to set buttons onClick events and it did not work.
Then, I read the documentations and tried the second solution, which is also did not work but I get an error:

```
ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'Button' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.
```

I understand what the error is, but I am very confused. After Unity 2019.1, I can't find the UnityEngine.UI library in Unity Documentations but if I use in script I can use it without any error. So depend on the documentation I must use UnityEngine.UIElements library but if I use, how can I make buttons derive from MonoBehaviour or others?

Comment: This is the link for Unity Documentation version 2020.3(Button Page) : https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UIElements.Button.html

Unity Documentation vesion 2019.1(Button Page):
https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to change the buttons click event at all.
Rather those can be a "static" click event that return what button index was clicked.

```
[0] Button 1 -> ButtonClicked(0)
[1] Button 2 -> ButtonClicked(1)
[2] Button 3 -> ButtonClicked(2)
```

You can then have the answers in an array

```
[0] Answer 1
[1] Answer 2
[2] Answer 3
```

and use the clicked buttons index to determine which answer was picked.

When you go to ask a new question, all you have to do is create (or replace values of) the answers array with the relevant answers (in any order you wish).